# Find the derived set of the $A = \{2,3\}$ for two topologies on the integers.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

In this post the  $\mathbb Z$ means the set of the integers.

The topological space, $(\mathbb Z, T_t)$ has subbasis, $T = \{\{2m,2m+1,2m+2 \vert m \in \mathbb Z\}\}$

The topological space, $(\mathbb Z, T_s)$ has subbasis, $S = \{ \{2m-1,2m, 2m+1 \} \vert m \in \mathbb Z\}$

Find the derived set of the $A = \{2,3\}$  for each topological spaces.

I'm tired to find the basis by finitely intersecting of the subbaiss. Then, form of the open sets in $(\mathbb Z, T_S)$ are either $\{2m-1\} $ or $\{2m-1,2m, 2m+1 \}$. With the same method,  form of the opens sets would be $\{2m\} $ or $\{2m,2m+1, 2m+2 \}$ for the $(\mathbb{Z}, T_t)$ case. So my answer is $A' = \{2,4\}$ in the $(\mathbb{Z}, T_s)$. And $A' =\{1,3\} $ in the $(\mathbb{Z}, T_t)$.

But the answers were $A' = \{2,4,6\}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}, T_s)$ and $A' = \{3,5\}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}, T_t)$. I can't understand why the answer should that be. Is my answer right?

Comment: That answer is wrong. The number $6$ does *not* belong to $\{2,3\}'$ since the  set $\{5,6,7\}$ is a neighborhood of $6$ in $(\Bbb Z,T_s)$ which has no element of $\{2,3\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider $A=\{2,3\}$ in $(\Bbb Z, T_t)$.

In this topology all even integers are isolated (e.g. $\{2\}=\{2,3,4\} \cap \{0,1,2\}$ etc.) and every neighbourhood of an odd one contains both of its neighbours. So $\{2,3\}'=\{1,3\}$ and not $\{3,5\}$, $5$ has a neighbourhood $\{4,5,6\}$ which is entirely disjoint from $A$ so is certainly not a limit point of it.

Now for $A$ in $(\Bbb Z, T_t)$, which is sort of symmetric: all odd integers are isolated and even ones have neighbourhoods that contain their neighbours. So $A'=\{2,4\}$ now, as you can easily check. $6$ has $\{5,6,7\}$ as a neighbourhood disjoint from $A$ now, so doesn't belong in it.

In short, I agree with the OP's answers and not with his book's answers.